# Need to determine the angle in this specific setup

Tags: geometry

(this is my first question here, please be considerate)

In this specific setup, I need to determine the specific angles, *x* and *y*. What seems simple, for some reason turns out to be a puzzle.

Here, it's clear that

*x + y = 130*

however, I can't introduce any other equation which would not be equivalent to this one.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRcpy.png)

Comment: Consider the quadrilateral ABCD. What is the sum of its angles?

Comment: Without more information, this doesn't appear solvable. You could, for example shrink the triangle on the right while keeping all angles in that triangle constant and keeping the left triangle the same size. Though they'd still add to 130, this would necessarily change the specific values of $x$ and $y$. Do you know anything about any lengths?

Comment: @martycohen this is the same fact. you still just get an equation in $x+y$

Comment: @jgd1729: thanks for the idea but somehow I can't see this. I thought this could be undetermined but trying to shrink the right gets me to the point where angles at left are changed.

Comment: @Malady: You are right. It looks like angles are not enough. Might have to look at lengths with the sine and cosine laws. Or, it might not be solvable.

Comment: @JuliannaZ here's a drawing of what I mean https://ibb.co/BBtcZ41 . Notice that as long as B'C' is parallel to BC, all the labeled information is the same, but $x'$ and $y'$ are clearly different from $x$ and $y$

Comment: @jgd1729: that's what I've been missing, thanks! You could post this as an answer.

Comment: @JuliannaZ, sure thing

Comment: @JeanMarie, that doesn't really help here since neither of the base angles are split by any of the line segments.

Comment: @jgd1729 You are right. I erase my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't enough information to answer the question. With just the angles labeled we can construct another shape that satisfies all the conditions in the image, but which clearly has different values for $x$ and $y$.

Consider what would happen if we were to take the original image and added a line segment $B'C'$, parallel to $BC$ as shown here:

[image]

Note that $\angle AB'C' =\angle ABC$ and $\angle B'C'E =\angle BCE$, so none of the labeled information has changed. But it is clear that $y'\neq y$ and $x'\neq x$.

Note also, we can choose $B'$ and $C'$ such that $y'$ is any angle $0^\text{o}<y'<130^\text{o}$. The longer $AB'$ is, the larger $y'$ will be.

Comment: In fact, the 2nd missing constraint could perhaps be that the altitude issued from C in triangle CEB is twice the altitude issued from D in triangle DAE.

Comment: That would indeed pin this down, but I don't know that we have enough information to assume this. Even if we accept the grid in the original image as being accurate, and further assume that all vertices fall precisely on a grid line, the altitude from $C$ would be 2.1 times the altitude from $D$.